# Hashcode java и его формирование

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, должен ли Hashcode объекта измениться если его поля изменились?

Comment: Не нужно использовать объект с изменяющимися полями, участвующими в вычислении `equals` и `hashCode` в качестве ключа `Map`, `HashSet` и т.п. т.к. вы этот объект после изменения полей не найдете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни фига не должен, смотрим сюда:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //создаем объект 
    MyMutable myMutable = new MyMutable(1, "Hello");
    System.out.println("intValue="+myMutable.getIntValue()+", stringValue="+myMutable.getStringValue()+", hashcode="+myMutable.hashCode());
    //мутируем (меняем) его свойства
    myMutable.setIntValue(2);
    myMutable.setStringValue("World!");
    //проверяем hashCode()
    System.out.println("intValue="+myMutable.getIntValue()+", stringValue="+myMutable.getStringValue()+", hashcode="+myMutable.hashCode());
  }
}

class MyMutable {
  private int intValue;
  private String stringValue;

  public MyMutable(int intValue, String stringValue) {
    this.intValue=intValue;
    this.stringValue=stringValue;
  }

  public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
    this.intValue=intValue;
  }

  public int getIntValue() {
    return this.intValue;
  }

  public void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
    this.stringValue=stringValue;
  }

  public String getStringValue() {
    return this.stringValue;
  }
}
```

Вывод:

> intValue=1, stringValue=Hello, hashcode=1829164700
>
> intValue=2, stringValue=World!, hashcode=1829164700

Специально ввел 2 разных поля, все равно при их изменении `hashCode()` не пересчитывается и остается прежним.

**Update**

по следам дискуссии в комментариях:

1) В дефолтной реализации `hashCode()` он не будет меняться при мутации объекта

2) Чтобы он менялся необходимо переопределять `hashCode()`, например для приведенного примера приблизительно так:

```
public int hashCode() {
   return super.hashCode()+
       this.intValue+
       ((this.stringValue==null?0:this.stringValue.hashCode());
}
```

Comment: Мда. На основании чего такое поведение? Ибо по java докам должно быть наоборот.

Comment: Неверно читаете документацию...

Comment: Естественно, если не переопределять метод `hashCode`, то это почти случайное число.

Comment: Сергей, вопрос был не об этом, понятно, что в первоначальном определении генерируется почти случайное число, но далее при модификации объекта должен ли он меняться? Как выяснилось не должен (пока объект жив)

Comment: Честно говоря, я понял автора как "Нужно ли мне писать метод hashCode так, чтобы хэш менялся вместе с данными?"

Comment: Ну если подумать в этом смысл есть. Не просто так же рекомендовано его переопределять. Просто найти бы доку где описано такое поведение.

Comment: Для динамически изменяемого объекта используют собственный метод генерации хеша. Используйте собственный метод `hashCode()` для определения текущего состояния. По крайней мере, все исходники что я видел, в которых имеется сравнение по хешу объектов всегда использовался переопределённый метод.

Comment: @alexsafsafsd в смысле где описано поведение `Object.hashCode()`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну аргументируйте, где конкретное место с описанием такого поведения? Либо я не вижу его, либо оно в другом месте

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: @alexsafsafsd я на днях буквально выковыривал из исходников [ответ на похожий вопрос](https://toster.ru/q/537663#answer_1230726).

Answer (score 2):

https://habr.com/post/168195/

Одинаковые объекты — это объекты одного класса с одинаковым содержимым полей.

Если объекты одинаковые, то и хеш-коды одинаковые (но не наоборот, см. правило 3).

Comment: Гениально! А вы мой вопрос читали?

Comment: Всё гениальное просто. Если поля изменились, то это уже другой объект, а значит у него должен быть другой hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

Да, должен. Вот что по этому поводу пишут в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, **provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified**. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Это следует из второго пункта и выделенной части первого. Но стоит иметь ввиду, что реализация по умолчанию метода `hashCode` этим принципам не следует, поэтому её всегда надо переопределять.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто:
Если при описании своего объекта вы не переопределяете метод hashcode, то при его инициализации(вызов ***new***) ему присваивается идентификационный хеш - hash по умолчанию. Делается это при помощи стандартного **нативного** метода.
В этом случае поля вашего объекта никак не влияют на формирование *hashcode*, соответственно любые изменения этих полей не приведут к изменению *hashcode*. Стоит учитывать, что создание ***нового аналогичного*** объекта не гарантирует совпадение *hashcode*
Если же вы явно переопределили метод *hashcode* и вычисление hash - объекта завязали на значение своих полей, то при их изменении *hashcode* так же изменится

Answer (score -1):

Правильнее было бы использовать примерно такую модель, коль вы решили использовать собственный калькулятор хеша:

```
public class Test
{
    private int _a;
    private int _b;
    private int _c;

    public Test(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return _a ^ _b ^ _c;
    }
}
```

И не обязательно возвращать сгенерированный самой JVM хешкод объекта при запросе через `super.hashcode()`, если изменилось какое-то условие. На мой взгляд это моветон.

Comment: Ваш код наоборот моветон, а если класс имеет родителей со сложными свойствами? Вы будете игнорить изменение свойств родителя... вызывать `super.hashCode()` как раз необходимо

Comment: @Barmaley мой код на все 146% удовлетворяет потребности автора вопроса. Нет никакого смысла обсуждать вызов `super.hashCode()` в данном контексте задачи. А использовать мой пример в вашем случае естественно моветон. Никто обратное и не утверждал.